# show all in query_posts on category.php?

Tags: query-posts

I want to be able to switch back and forth by clicking an anchor tag preferably, between showing a subset of posts and showing all posts, the code I am using is:

```
query_posts($query_string . '&posts_per_page=-1');
```

or

```
query_posts( array(
'posts_per_page' => 45,
//'paged' => ( get_query_var('page') ? get_query_var('page') : 1 ),
));
```

(paged isn't working)

Any way to do this? The problem is I need the 45 limit to show by default, and then a show all anchor tag or button that the user can click.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!
Donna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a url parameter for posts per page. Something like this:

```
$pppage = ( get_query_var( 'posts_per_page' ) == 'all' ) ? -1 : 45;
query_posts( array(
    'posts_per_page' => $pppage
) );
```

then you can set your URL with the parameter `posts_per_page=all` if you want to show all the posts, if it doesn't find that parameter it will default to 45 posts. You can rewrite this parameter to something like `/all/` to show all.

Comment: Thanks! Would I put that in the functions.php file?

Comment: You use it wherever your current query is. You'll probably want to do the rewrite in functions.php though.